# How to add google translate plug in in jekyll site?

Tags: ruby

I am start learning web developing recently. Now I am making a jekyll blog. And I want to add google translate in my blog. But I don't understand how to add google translate in jekyll. Please help.

Comment: do you mean multi language jekyll blog? i am not sure if there is plugin for google translate in jekyll

Comment: I find this jekyll theme http://pranavrajs.github.io/swift/blog/2014/09/09/example/          i want to khow how to add google translate in my jekyll theme